# Working with conan modules which change frequently

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I'have a conan structure that looks like this:

```
source/Module1
source/Module2
source/Module3
source/Application
```

Module3 depends on Module2 depends on Module1. 
I build those modules by calling "conan create  mine/stable"

I have a CMakeLists.txt in my Application which uses the conan.cmake file by calling

```
conan_cmake_run(REQUIRES
    Module1/1.0@mine/stable
    Module2/1.0@mine/stable
    Module3/1.0@mine/stable
    BASIC_SETUP
    BUILD missing outdated)
```

When I change anything in a module and call the "conan create ..." command and afterwards rebuild my application by using "cmake .. && cmake --build ." the changes are only visible in some cases. 
I cannot derive when a change from a module will be taken by the compiliation step in the Application and when it doesn't.

Is there a better strategy to include modules in a C++ Application with Conan? Especially if the modules change frequently and multiple devs working on the code.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you need to clear cmake cache prior to invoking "cmake .. && cmake --build"

Comment: You should try https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/developing_packages/workspaces.html which is designed for multiple modules. Also there is a full example here: https://github.com/conan-io/examples/tree/master/features/workspace/cmake

Comment: I'm going to try the workspace approach